# How to pass sqlparameter to IN()?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

For some reason the Sqlparameter for my IN() clause is not working. The code compiles fine, and the query works if I substitute the parameter with the actual values

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (User user in UserList)
            {
                sb.Append(user.UserId + ",");
            }

            string userIds = sb.ToString();
            userIds = userIds.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' });


SELECT userId, username 
FROM Users 
WHERE userId IN (@UserIds)
```

Comment: The commas have to be between strings, not within a string.

Comment: The commas separate each userid

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You have to create one parameter for each value that you want in the `IN` clause.

The SQL needs to look like this:

```
SELECT userId, username 
FROM Users 
WHERE userId IN (@UserId1, @UserId2, @UserId3, ...)
```

So you need to create the parameters **and** the `IN` clause in the `foreach` loop.
Something like this (out of my head, untested):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int i = 1;

foreach (User user in UserList)
{
    // IN clause
    sb.Append("@UserId" + i.ToString() + ",");

    // parameter
    YourCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId" + i.ToString(), user.UserId);

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Remember remove last comma at the end, because with example above it will be in (@userId,)

Comment: Its, very old post, but just one more update to answer. to help one more googler, ;) You can make use of xml as parameter to get similar effect of CSV and in clause Query -
 SELECT userId, username 
FROM Users u1 INNER JOIN @UsersID.nodes('/ID') T(col) ON u1.userId = t.col.value('.', 'int')

Comment: Huge warning to anyone using this. SQL Server defaults to 2100 as a maximum number of parameters.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using SQL 2008, you can create a stored procedure which accepts a Table Valued Parameter (TVP) and use ADO.net to execute the stored procedure and pass a datatable to it:

First, you need to create the Type in SQL server:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[udt_UserId] AS TABLE(
    [UserId] [int] NULL
)
```

Then, you need to write a stored procedure which accepts this type as a parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_DoSomethingWithTableTypedParameter]
(
   @UserIdList udt_UserId READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN

        SELECT userId, username 
        FROM Users 
        WHERE userId IN (SELECT UserId FROM @UserIDList) 

END
```

Now from .net, you cannot use LINQ since it does not support Table Valued Parameters yet; so you have to write a function which does plain old ADO.net, takes a DataTable, and passes it to the stored procedure: I've written a generic function I use which can do this for any stored procedure as long as it takes just the one table-typed parameter, regardless of what it is;

```
    public static int ExecStoredProcWithTVP(DbConnection connection, string storedProcedureName, string tableName, string tableTypeName, DataTable dt)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter p = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(tableName, dt);
            p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            p.TypeName = tableTypeName;

            conn.Open();
            int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // or could execute reader and pass a Func<T> to perform action on the datareader;
            conn.Close();

            return rowsAffected;
        }
    }
```

Then you can write DAL functions which use this utility function with actual names of stored procedures; to build on the example in your question, here is what the code would look like:

```
    public int usp_DoSomethingWithTableTypedParameter(List<UserID> userIdList)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("UserId", typeof(int));

        foreach (var userId in updateList)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { userId });
        }

        int rowsAffected = ExecStoredProcWithTVP(Connection, "usp_DoSomethingWithTableTypedParameter", "@UserIdList", "udt_UserId", dt);
        return rowsAffected;
    }
```

Note the "connection" parameter above - I actually use this type of function in a partial DataContext class to extend LINQ DataContext with my TVP functionality, and still use the (using var context = new MyDataContext()) syntax with these methods.

This will only work if you are using SQL Server 2008 - hopefully you are and if not, this could be a great reason to upgrade! Of course in most cases and large production environments this is not that easy, but FWIW I think this is the best way of doing this if you have the technology available.

Comment: If most of your tables use the same type for their PK, could you not make a generalized reusable ID parameter UDT?  

Like:CREATE TYPE [dbo].[udt_IntId] AS TABLE([Id] [int] NULL)

to be reused in *any* case where you need to do a sql IN clause on the int primary key id?

Answer (score 9):

Possible "cleaner" version:

```
StringBuilder B = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < UserList.Count; i++)
     YourCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@UserId{i}", UserList[i].UserId);
B.Append(String.Join(",", YourCommand.Parameters.Select(x => x.Name)));
```

Comment: I don't get it. When you are doing YourCommand.Parameters.Select(x => x.Name) you have a list like: John, Mary, ...
And not a list of User1,User2, User3.

Comment: @LucaCosta you get a +1 for the use of string interpolation and a -1 for nitpicking my "clean" code lol j/k good job :)

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server sees your `IN` clause as:

```
IN ('a,b,c')
```

What it needs to look like is:

```
IN ('a','b','c')
```

There is a better way to do what you're trying to do.

- If the user id's are in the DB, then the `IN` clause should be changed to a subquery, like so:

  `IN (SELECT UserID FROM someTable WHERE someConditions)`
- This is a hack -- it doesn't work well with indexes, and you have to be careful it works right with your data, but I've used it successfully in the past:

  `@UserIDs LIKE '%,' + UserID + ',%' -- also requires @UserID to begin and end with a comma`

Comment: +1 for your hack. Even if it probably forces a full scan, and prevents the optimiser from doing its job, it's a clever trick, that's usable with Access as well.

Comment: @John: I have tried this: `IN (@param)`  and then  `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", "'a','b','c'");` but this is unsuccessful.  Can you please advice on this.

Comment: @user1671639 If you always have 3 parameters, then you can use `IN (@param1, @param2, @param3)` and then `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", "a"); command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", "b"); command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", "c");`. If you don't always have 3 values, perhaps you should ask a new stackoverflow.com question, provide sufficient detail, and point me to the new question. I bet several people will try to answer right away.

Comment: @John:Thanks.  But I got found a simple way and this works perfectly `string param="'a','b','c'";` and then `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE IN (" + param + ")";`.  Please advice whether this is a correct way or not.

Comment: @user1671639 If a, b, and c are user input, then your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack. That's why you should use the Parameter object instead. If you want to discuss this further, please create a new stackoverflow.com question.