# Dynamically add parameter to a 'IN' clause in a query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am attempting to query an `MS Access` DB with `C#`

Static query is -

```
Select FieldID , CDGroups.CDGroupID , Priority
from Fields , CDGroups
where Fields.CDGroupID = CDGroups.CDGroupID
  and Fields.FieldID in ('f1','f2','f3')
order by Priority
```

I need to replace f1,f2.. FieldID from `fieldIdList(List<string> fieldIdList)` which contains all these fields

How can I go about it?

Comment: what's the language you're programming in, and entity framework or other, are you using LINQ?

Comment: I am connecting c# app with access databse,no I am not using LINQ.

Comment: You still need to show some code, otherwise the best you can hope for here is "well, then do it"

Comment: What do you want to get? The list of CDGroupID that have 'f1','f2' and 'f3'?

Comment: @Devart list of CDGroupID with there corrsponding field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following code:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (string fieldId in fieldIdList)
                {
                    sb.Append("'" + fieldId + "',");
                }

                string fieldList = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',');

                string queryString =
                    "Select FieldID , CDGroups.CDGroupID , Priority from Fields , CDGroups where Fields.CDGroupID = CDGroups.CDGroupID and Fields.FieldID in (" + fieldList + ") order by Priority";
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way would be to use SQL parameters.
To do this, you need to loop through your list and create one parameter per list item - in the SQL string **and** in your query's list of SQL parameters.

Take a look at this answer to a similar question:
[How to pass sqlparameter to IN()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384446/how-to-pass-sqlparameter-to-in/9384566#9384566)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var listId= string.Join(",", fieldIdList.Select(m => string.Format("'{0}'", m)));;
```

then

```
"Field.FieldID in (" + listId+ ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT CDGroupID FROM fields
  WHERE FieldID IN ('f1', 'f2', 'f3')
  GROUP BY CDGroupID
  HAVING(COUNT(DISTINCT FieldID)) >= 3
```

It will show a list of CDGroupID that have 'f1','f2' and 'f3' at least. If you want to show ones that have just 'f1','f2' and 'f3', then change WHERE condition to 'HAVING(COUNT(DISTINCT FieldID)) >= 3'.