# SQL and ASP.NET WHERE IN generates wrong

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have this line of code:

```
sql += " AND lc.name IN ('" + String.Join(",", id.type.ToArray()) + "')";
```

There are two items in id.type and this code generates this:

```
AND lc.name IN ('towns back to back,towns 3 storey')
```

Which will not work because it should be like this:

```
AND lc.name IN ('towns back to back' , 'towns 3 storey')
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `String.Join("','", id.type.ToArray())`

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Use parameters instead.

Comment: @ADyson Yes it's vulnerable, but in this case (IN clause), parameters cannot be used (unfortunately)

Comment: @HansKesting why not? It would be perfectly possible to pull the string into an array, and create a parameter for each item in the array.

Comment: @HansKesting probably a bit like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36458919/5947043

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a desirable approach, because it's open to SQL injection.  But there are a few things:

1. You have to accommodate for strings that contain single quotes.
2. It won't work if you just concatenate.  You have to wrap EACH item in single quotes.

Try:

```
sql += " AND lc.name IN (" + String.Join(",", id.type.ToArray().Select(i=>String.Format(i.Replace("'","''"),"'{0}'")) + ")";
```

Answer (score -1):

Use parameter to pass input string like

```
sql += " AND lc.name IN (@inputname)";
sqlcommand.parameters.AddWithValue("@inputname", String.Join("','", id.type.ToArray()))
```

Comment: IN clauses cannot be parameterized unless there is a fixed number of values.