# Using parameters in a Where clause

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I have not found an existing thread for exactly what I need. I have a reporting tool that allows me to ask user for input (Client) and pass to SQL as a parameter.

There could be multiple Clients or the word All. If parameter contains 'All' I need to select all records. If the parameter does not contain 'All' I only need to select the records in the parameter.

I found a few solutions that work if the parameter is only one value but mine is a list and needs to use the 'in' predicate. (I think)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS - MySql? Sql-Server? More often than not you should handle listed parameters in your code, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384446/how-to-pass-sqlparameter-to-in). Otherwise your alternative is dynamic SQL which I rarely suggest.

Comment: This will likely require features of your reporting tool.  What is it?

Comment: Sanit - Intersystems Cache and I would be interested in seeing a dynamic SQL suggestion rd - Its not well known I don't think. It is called Visual Data Miner and does have some features to handle this but I would like this to be done on the server side which is why I am hoping to find an SQL solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your datamodel, something like the following should do:

```
SELECT *
FROM clients
WHERE ID IN (@clients) OR 'All' IN @clients
```

Comment: Worked like a champ!

Comment: @CoSpringsGuy Glad I could help. In that case you could / should flag this answer as the accepted answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

When you speak about Caché, it means that you even have multiple ways how you execute your query. And also there are some ways how to achieve it. I would suggest to use different queries, for `ALL` records and for chosen. And you can use [IN](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_in) or [%INLIST](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_inlist) predicate.