# How can I pass a list parameter to an ODBC query in Excel (Microsoft Query)

Tags: excel, db2, odbc, parameter-passing, microsoft-query

I'm having some trouble passing a particular type of parameter from an Excel cell value to an ODBC query.  It's a DB2 database on an AS400 server, and I'm using the iSeries Access ODBC Driver from IBM.

Here is the query with hard-coded values:

```
SELECT STKB.BXPART, STKB.BXSTOK, STKB.BXQTOH, STKB.BXUNIT
FROM CMSDAT.STKB STKB
WHERE (STKB.BXPART In ('BAG024','BAG709'))
```

And the desired result:

[image]

What i would like to do is pass the list from an Excel value to the parameter.  The query is modified like so:

```
SELECT STKB.BXPART, STKB.BXSTOK, STKB.BXQTOH, STKB.BXUNIT
FROM CMSDAT.STKB STKB
WHERE (STKB.BXPART In (?))
```

And the parameter is set to pull from a cell:
[image]

If I put one value in the cell, the query returns the results for that one value.  If I try more than one item the query returns empty.  I've tried the following values in the cell AA4:

```
('BAG024','BAG709')
(BAG024,BAG709)
'BAG024','BAG709'
BAG024,BAG709
```

Has anyone successfully used cell values for an 'in' parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameterized query from Excel with IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56284517/parameterized-query-from-excel-with-in-clause)

Comment: Yep good find, thanks.