# C# SqlDataAdapter - Select Command Concern

Tags: c#, sqldataadapter, selectcommand

I'm having trouble with my select command. The scenario is when i'm putting many value in my variable I got nothing but if i put only one value in variable it is working.

All I want is to run this script:

```
SELECT * 
FROM gsm00 a 
INNER JOIN gsd00 b ON a.idnum=b.idnum WHERE b.idnum IN ('0001','0002')
```

**Here's my sample code:**

```
string val= "0001" - this is working
```

`//string val= "0001,0002"` - this is not working

```
query = "SELECT * FROM gsm00 a INNER JOIN gsd00 b ON a.idnum=b.idnum WHERE b.idnum IN (@searchKey)";

MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, dbconfig.conn);
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchKey", val);
dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
dataAdapter.Dispose();
```

Comment: seems like the single quotes are the problem...

Comment: Hi, I've tried this one val= "'0001','0002'" but still not working.

Comment: yes, the single quotes will be escaped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, your @searchKey Value ist "0001" and this means your statement looks like

```
SELECT * FROM gsm00 a INNER JOIN gsd00 b ON a.idnum=b.idnum WHERE b.idnum IN ('0001')
```

this works because it is 1 parameter and the internal paramter handling is putting single-quotes around it.

The seconds case looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM gsm00 a INNER JOIN gsd00 b ON a.idnum=b.idnum WHERE b.idnum IN ('0001,0002')
```

but it has to look like

```
SELECT * FROM gsm00 a INNER JOIN gsd00 b ON a.idnum=b.idnum WHERE b.idnum IN ('0001','0002')
```

Its not implicitly possible to check from your statement if its 1 paremeter or multiple parameters because the "," can be a part of your IN-Clause value.

This is a similar question with solutions, maybe you have also a look at this:

[How to pass sqlparameter to IN()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384446/how-to-pass-sqlparameter-to-in)

Answer (score -1):

try:

```cs
query = "SELECT * FROM gsm00 a INNER JOIN gsd00 b ON a.idnum=b.idnum WHERE b.idnum IN ({@searchKey})";
...
var a = new string [] {"0001", "0002" } ;
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.AddArrayParameters("@searchKey", a );
```